# monerod --test-drop-download vs --fast-block-sync

Tags: monerod, synchronization

As per the help command

> **--test-drop-download** : For net tests: in download, discard ALL
> blocks instead checking/saving them (very fast)
>
> **--fast-block-sync** arg (=1) : Sync up most of the way by using embedded, known block hashes.

What is the difference between these two modes of syncing?

Answer (score 3):

The help strings pretty much describe the differences.

The `--test-drop-download` version wont save the blocks, it's used for testing downloading of blocks.

The `--fast-block-sync` is a mode for normal operation (not testing) which will still save the downloaded blocks.